# Tooltips that don't overlap in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible to apply some kind of force layout to tooltips in a multiseries line chart so that the tooltips don't overlap and obscure one another when two series are very close together? Or is there another way to achieve that outcome?

Comment: Yes, see for example [here](http://www.larsko.org/v/igdp/index-alt.html) where I've done this for labels.

Comment: Thanks! I still couldn't figure it out after looking at your example. Ended up drawing a table.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff the link is now broken... do you have the new link? Thanks!

Comment: @tato Sure, see https://larskotthoff.github.io/v-igdp/index.html